# How to unzip war file into the new folder(or to the another drive) using cmd in windows

Tags: java, windows, jar, war

I have war file `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\Test.war`
I want extract into new new directory
For this i used.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin> jar -xvf Test.jar
```

But it extracted into bin folder with out creating new folder.

Answer (score 1):

First create a new directory `Test`, and then cd into that directory and then:
`jar -xvf ../Test.jar`

Comment: But its giving me the like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin

Comment: But its giving me error like 'jar' is not recognized as an iternal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: For that error you need to add C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin to your %PATH% You can do this every time in the command line by running: set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin , or you may set it permanently in system environment in control panel.

Comment: mani do you know how to run this in java. I try this but its not working please help me (String[] command = new String[3];
command[0] = "cmd";command[1] = "/c";command[2] = "set path=c://Program Files//Java//jdk1.8.0_20//bin && jar -xvf m.war";
                 

                 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);